# Is SAT in P if there are exponentially many clauses in the number of variables?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, satisfiability, polynomial-time

I define a *long CNF* to contain at least $2^\frac{n}{2}$ clauses, where $n$ is the number of its variables. Let $\text{Long-SAT}=\{\phi: \phi$ is a satisfiable long CNF formula$\}$.

I'd like to know why $\text{Long-SAT} \in P$. First I thought it is $\text{NPC}$ since I can do a polynomial-time reduction from $\text{SAT}$ to $\text{Long-SAT}$, no?

But maybe I can reduce $\text{2-SAT}$ to $\text{Long-SAT}$? How do I do that?

Comment: @Numerator: Watch out in the last sentence in the question.  Reducing an easy problem (2-SAT in this case) to your problem does not mean that your problem is easy.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: We try to keep on top of weird tags. Please feel free to edit the occasional occurrence. If you spot wide-spread (mis)use or meet opposition, please take it to meta (rather than discussing in the comments below a question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it's trivially in **P** as the length of the formula is exponential in the number of variables. Hence all $2^{n}$ truth assignments can be generated and checked in polynomial time in the length of the formula.

Comment: But a $2^n$ checks is still defined as plynoimal time?

Comment: Remember that to be in P you want an algorithm that runs in polynomial time in the size of the input. In this case, if we denote the size of the input as N we know that $\text{#clauses } \leq N$. Hence we also have $n=O(log N)$ so the $2^n$ assignments only amount to a polynomial in the overall input size $N$. Don't let texts trick you when they use the variable $n$, it's just a variable, not a special magic number that is always the best measure for the size of the input. Sorry about the formatting, I'm typing this on my phone.

Comment: @Numerator: you are doing $2^{\log n}=n$ checks, where $n$ is the length of the input.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, the answer is trivial as [Luke points out](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2676/1546). However, as you seem to have come up with the definition yourself, note this.

For SAT, so-called phase transitions regarding the ratio of variable count to clause count have been observed [1,2]. If it is small, instances are easy, and hard if it is large. There seems to be a more or less sharp transition from easy to hard. This seems to be an [active area of research](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=phase+transition+satisfiability&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39&as_ylo=2011). [cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2676/1546) has some more on this phenomenon.

So, if you adjust your definition of "long" to *polynomial* blowup, you might indeed get an non-trivially easy class -- that is, in P -- just because you have much more clauses than variables.

---

1. [The SAT Phase Transition](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/MY_DAI_OLD_FTP/rp679.pdf) by I. P. Gent (1994)
2. [Determining computational complexity from characteristic 'phase transitions'](http://leibniz.cs.huji.ac.il/tr/532.pdf) by R. Monasson, R. Zecchina et al. (1999)

Comment: Actually, it's not an easy-hard but rather easy-hard-easy the pattern regarding the phase transition. There are 2 regions: underconstrained and overconstrained. In the first one, solutions are densely distributed, so you succeed quickly. In the second one you fail quickly: any reasonable algorithm finds a solution if such exists (a strong basin of attraction), and if there's no solution a backtracking algorithm can establish that quickly since potential solution paths are cut off early. Hard problems are on the boundary of these regions: the probability of a solution is low but non-negligible.